# Codable Conformance with Erased Types?

Tags: swift, generics, casting, codable, type-erasure

I'm trying to write a generic function to parse several different data types.

Originally this method only worked for Codable types, so its generic type was constrained with `<T: Codable>` and all was well. Now though, I am attempting to expand it to *check* if the return type is Codable, and parse the data accordingly based on that check

```
func parse<T>(from data: Data) throws -> T? {

    switch T.self {
    case is Codable:

        // convince the compiler that T is Codable

        return try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)

    case is [String: Any].Type:

        return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? T

    default:
        return nil
    }

}
```

So you can see that the type-checking works fine, but I'm stuck on getting `JSONDecoder().decode(:)` to accept `T` as a `Codable` type once I've checked that it is. The above code doesn't compile, with the errors

`Cannot convert value of type 'T' (generic parameter of instance method 'parse(from:)') to expected argument type 'T' (generic parameter of instance method 'decode(_:from:)')` 
and 
`In argument type 'T.Type', 'T' does not conform to expected type 'Decodable'`

I've tried a number of casting techniques, like `let decodableT: <T & Decodable> = T.self` etc., but all have failed-- usually based on the fact that `Decodable` is a protocol and `T` is a concrete type.

Is it possible to (conditionally) reintroduce protocol conformance to an erased type like this? I'd appreciate any ideas you have, either for solving this approach or for similar generic-parsing approaches that might be more successful here.

EDIT: A Complication

@vadian helpfully suggested creating two `parse(:)` methods with different type constraints, to handle all cases with one signature. That's a great solution in many cases, and if you're stumbling across this question later it may very well solve your conundrum.

Unfortunately, in this only works if the type is known at the time that `parse(:)` is invoked-- and in my application this method is called by another generic method, meaning that the type is already erased and the compiler can't pick a correctly-constrained `parse(:)` implementation.

So, to clarify the crux of this question: is it possible to conditionally/optionally add type information (e.g. protocol conformance) *back* to an erased type? In other words, once a type has become `<T>` is there any way to cast it to `<T: Decodable>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can conditionally cast `T.self` to `Decodable.Type` in order to get a metatype that describes an underlying `Decodable` conforming type:

```
  switch T.self {
  case let decodableType as Decodable.Type:
```

However, if we try to pass `decodableType` to `JSONDecoder`, we have a problem:

```
// error: Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type
// '(Decodable.Type, from: Data)'
return try? JSONDecoder().decode(decodableType, from: data)
```

This doesn't work because [`decode(_:from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/2895189-decode) has a generic placeholder `T : Decodable`:

```
func decode<T : Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data) throws -> T
```

and we cannot satisfy `T.Type` with `Decodable.Type` because `Decodable` [doesn't conform to itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878).

As explored in the above linked Q&A, one workaround for this issue is to *open* the `Decodable.Type` value in order to dig out the underlying concrete type that conforms to `Decodable` – which we can then use to satisfy `T`.

This can be done with a protocol extension:

```
extension Decodable {
  static func openedJSONDecode(
    using decoder: JSONDecoder, from data: Data
  ) throws -> Self {
    return try decoder.decode(self, from: data)
  }
}
```

Which we can then call as:

```
return try? (decodableType.openedJSONDecode(using: JSONDecoder(), from: data) as! T)
```

You'll note that we've had to insert a force cast to `T`. This is due to the fact that by casting `T.self` to `Decodable.Type` we erased the fact that the metatype also describes the type `T`. Therefore we need to force cast in order to get this information back.

All in all, you'll want your function to look something like this:

```
func jsonDecode<T>(_ metatype: T.Type, from data: Data) throws -> T {
  switch metatype {
  case let codableType as Decodable.Type:
    let decoded = try codableType.openedJSONDecode(
      using: JSONDecoder(), from: data
    )

    // The force cast `as! T` is guaranteed to always succeed due to the fact
    // that we're decoding using `metatype: T.Type`. The cast to
    // `Decodable.Type` unfortunately erases this information.
    return decoded as! T

  case is [String: Any].Type, is [Any].Type:
    let rawDecoded = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    guard let decoded = rawDecoded as? T else {
      throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(
        type(of: rawDecoded), .init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: """
        Expected to decode \(metatype), found \(type(of: rawDecoded)) instead.
        """)
      )
    }
    return decoded

  default:
    fatalError("\(metatype) is not Decodable nor [String: Any] nor [Any]")
  }
}
```

I have made a couple of other changes:

- Changed the return type from `T?` to `T`. In general, you either want to handle errors by having the function return an optional or by having it throw – it can be quite confusing for the caller to handle both.
- Added an explicit parameter for `T.Type`. This avoids relying on the caller to use return type inference in order to satisfy `T`, which IMO is a similar pattern to overloading by return type [which is discouraged by the API design guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#similar-methods-can-share-a-base-name).
- Made the `default:` case `fatalError` as it should probably be a programmer error to supply a non-decodable type.

Comment: This is a very powerful and general answer, but the need for `openedJSONDecode` feels like a syntax trick thats pointing to a problem in Swift generics. The information is there, but the compiler can't figure it out without flipping the syntax. That's bothering me even more than the `as! T` (which is definitely bothering me, because it feels the compiler should be able to prove this). I'm just muttering here, but I'm interested if there's any deeper discussions going on about this.

Comment: @RobNapier Yup, we're definitely working around a current limitation of the language here! The ability to open existentials yourself [is a part of the generics manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#opening-existentials), so if/when that's implemented it'll no longer be needed to (ab)use protocol extensions like this.

Comment: Another idea that has been thrown around is that the compiler could implicitly open existentials for you when passing one as an argument to a generic-typed parameter, so you could pass a `Decodable.Type` straight to a `T.Type` parameter where `T : Decodable` and the compiler would automatically unbox the `Decodable.Type` for you.

Comment: But even with existential opening, you'd still need the `as! T` at the end in order to get back to a concrete type (as opposed to `Decodable`). Really what the language needs is some kind of way of conditionally constraining generic placeholders at runtime, e.g `if T : Decodable { /* within this scope, T is now Decodable */ }`. I can't recall any previous discussion on such a feature though.

Comment: Thank you for such an in-depth response @Hamish-- this works perfectly!

Comment: Answer is great, but can be improved. You actually can declare more generic `openedDecode(using decoder: Decoder) throws -> Self { return try self.init(from: decoder)  }` which will take any decoder, not only JSON.